# WCF service using wildcard cert giving a DNS identity error

Tags: wcf, dns, certificate, x509certificate

I have a WCF web service that is setup to use Message based security.  The service is using a wildcard certificate for securing the message: *.domain.com

After renewing the SSL cert, the service now throws the following error:

"Identity check failed for outgoing message.  The expected DNS identity of the remote endpoint was '*.domain.com' but the remote endpoint provided DNS claim 'domain.com'. ..."

How do I fix this so the service still responds with *.domain.com as the DNS claim?

Unfortunately updating the client configs is not really an option to use the new DNS claim via the DNS identity property.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the SANs list on the Wild Card Cert.  The order that the domains were listed were:

```
*.domain.com
domain.com
```

WCF was basically always resolving to the last item in the SANs list.  I did stumble across a few articles where Office Communicator had a similar issue. I'm not sure if this is a WCF bug or not.

My solution was to ask the Certificate Authority to generate me a wildcard cert without the SANs attribute.

Comment: Does anyone know why this seems to only happen sporadically?  We have been using the same wild card certificate for a few years with multiples services and we just started having this issue with one client.

Answer (score 5):

This is an bug in WCF. Visit the connect site and upvote if its a blocking issue. http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/683178/wcf-x509-certificate-validation-only-checks-last-dnsname-in-subject-alternative-name

Comment: This link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

The dns setting for the client is simply used to verify the certificates authenticity, so you can simply set the dns of the client to "domain.com" instead of "service.domain.com".